# Problem with Apache and Ruby Mechanize gem

Tags: php, ruby, apache

I have a cgi script written in Ruby that is called from a php script.  When calling the cgi script I am running into an error loading mechanize:

```
require 'mechanize'
```

The error is:

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- mechanize (LoadError)
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
```

The gem is installed and I can load it from irb.  I'm not real sure how to even go about troubleshooting this.  Here is my gem env output if it helps:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.5.0
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2010-08-18 patchlevel 0) [i386-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.9
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9
     - /home/<username>/.gem/ruby/1.9
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Any success yet? I am facing the same issue.